# If a function is defined on a closed interval, does the derivative exist at the interval edges?

Tags: calculus, limits, derivatives

For example,

let $f(x) = x, x \in [1,2]$

does the derivative exist at $1$? and why?

Comment: This does not need to be true. Imagine $f(x) = 0$ otherwise.

Comment: There may or may not be a one-sided derivative at an end, depending on whether or not the ordinary difference quotient you use to define the derivative has a limit from the "inside" of the interval at that end.

Comment: so there could be a one-sided derivative? assuming that's true, we can't say the derivative exist at the edges, can we?

Comment: Consider $f(x)=\sqrt {1-x^2}$ for $|x|\leq 1.$ Or consider $g(x)$ for $x\in [0,1]$ where $g(0)=0$, and $g(x)=x \sin (1/x)$ for $x\in (0,1].$

Comment: Just as you cannot say an arbitrary function will be differentiable at points in the interval, you also cannot say that it will be differentiable at the edges. At the edge, you can have a one-sided derivative. If you have it, it says nothing about how the function behaves outside the interval. The function need not even exist outside the interval. But inside, it tells you the slope of the function on that side of the point, just as for points in the interior.

Comment: That's what I thought too, but in my textbook from high-school, often there's a question that implies that some functions can be defined on a closed interval only, then can be differentiated at the edges! so I looked up a formal definition of the limit and came to the conclusion, that either that definition wasn't complete, or we can say that the limit of a function at a value from a side it isn't defined on, is equal to whatever we want!

Comment: since I saw in a course that (if P then Q) is true when P is false! and that definition says that for every epsilon > 0 there exists a delta > 0 such that IF 0 < |x-c| < delta, then |f(x)-L| < epsilon.